# Prevent submitting AJAX requests when user has logged out...?

Tags: asp.net

In my project ASP.NET I am submitting a data using JQuery.
I need some solution for logout page that still displaying on the user's browser.

If user will click on the page it will post the request the server.
Although the request may not be proceed on server but I get "success" code on complete event also the status code shown me 200.

Is there any way to prevent submitting AJAX request when user has logged out...?

Comment: Check for the session in the web method. If session is null or invalid then respond accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will not be able to stop the request.

You can control your response to it though.

Return some error code that will tell your script that the user is logged out, and then your javascript can direct the user to a login screen.

If the user is logged out, the 200 response that you are getting is probably the login page. You can check the contents of the response in such cases and detect a logout.

Comment: Yes you are right. 200 code is return because of login page. 
Now I can do that I want... <br/>

Answer (score 0):

Generally login / session is handled by cookies which are sent with every request sent to server. Let it be browser URL or an ajax call. If you delete the cookies upon logout, subsequent ajax calls can be replied with please login again message.